# Css issue with my navigation

Tags: css

I have a sticky navigation, but my problem is the navigation jumps a little as I begin scrolling

http://testdev.co.za/tyme/info/

Can anyone show me in the css where the problem is.

Comment: Do not see any problems? It doesn't jump in google chrome?

Comment: @Izekid It jumps in Chrome, too.

Comment: I see the jump too - if you smooth scroll with the wheel button, or touch screen. There's a chance it has something to do with line height for `l-subheader at_middle`, which your plugin is setting...

Comment: on a side note, as your website loads pretty slowly, you might want to add a preloader...

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the position of your navigation bar using this code

```
position: fixed;
```

may be it will help you

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `padding-top: 25px` from the `.l-canvas.headerpos_fixed .l-header.state_sticky` class in `custom-vb.css`.

Then you need to add `padding-top: 25px` to the `.l-canvas.type_wide .l-subheader, .l-canvas.type_boxed .l-submain` class in the same css file.

Sooooo, in `custom-vb.css`:

```
.l-canvas.headerpos_fixed .l-header.state_sticky {

}

.l-canvas.type_wide .l-subheader, .l-canvas.type_boxed .l-submain {
    min-height: 100px !important;
    padding top: 25px;
}
```

Any problems let me know.